# Windows 7 64-bit Program Files

Tags: windows-7

There are two folders:
C:\Program Files and
C:\Program Files (x86)

Can I remove the folder "Program Files (x86)"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. On a 64-bit system, there will be two folder, one for 64-bit programs and the other for 32-bit (x86). Many apps only have 32-bit versions, since 64-bit is unnecessary. Removing that folder will delete all of these programs, which is probably the bulk of the ones you have installed. Even some built-in Windows apps are in this folder. Deleting it will render them useless.

Answer (score 0):

Can you or should you?  You probably can if you really want to, but you shouldn't unless you know what every file in it is for and that it won't ever be needed.  It is where 32-bit programs are installed, and if there is anything in it, that means an application that was installed on the system put it there because it was a 32-bit program.